# hidden attribute in input tag from html form

Tags: php, html, hidden

I am trying to get the posted information and display the info using the following code:

**PHP code:**

```
        $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if(isset($_POST['send'])){                
            $words = htmlspecialchars($_POST['board']);
            print "<b>".$words."</b>";
        }            ​​​​
```

**HTML code**:

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" method=post> <!--$self is the directory of the page itself-->
        <p><i>Comment</i></p>
        <textarea name="board" rows="20" cols="10"></textarea>
        <input name="send" type="hidden" />
        <p><input type='submit' value='send' /></p>
</form>
```

The code above will work as I intented. However, if I get rid of the input name="send" type="hidden", the user input message will not show up once the send button is clicked. Why would this happen?

Comment: What's the name of your submit button? ;)

Comment: you can remove the `action="<?php $self?>"` since you are directing it on the same page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add name='send' to your submit button, your PHP code is reading the name of the form elements, and you have not specified one for your submit button.

```
<form action="<?php $self ?>" method=post> <!--$self is the directory of the page itself-->
        <p><i>Comment</i></p>
        <textarea name="board" rows="20" cols="10"></textarea>
        <p><input type='submit' name='send' value='send' /></p>
</form>
```

Also, a quick note - you can change your form method to GET instead of POST to easily see what form data you're sending in the URL bar.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are checking that the POST variable "send" isset. That is what you named your hidden input.

You should add a `name` to your submit input. Example:

```
    <p><input type='submit' name="submit_button" value='send' /></p>
```

Now in your php, check for the `name` of your submit button. I used "submit_button" in this example. Here is modified code example:

```
    $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if(isset($_POST['submit_button'])){                
        $words = htmlspecialchars($_POST['board']);
        print "<b>".$words."</b>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont have to bother naming your send button or anything, just remove that `hidden` line...

and change your php to....

```
 $self = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if(isset($_POST)){                
        $words = htmlspecialchars($_POST['board']);
        print "<b>".$words."</b>";
    }
```